# Multiple Rows and Columns to Single Column Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have different data on multiple rows and columns in Excel and I want all the data to be on a single Column. I tried the **Transpose Function** but it's not helping me to get what I want.

This is what I have right now:

[image]

And this is what I want to get:

[image]

Can anyone kindly tell me how I can achieve that? Any built in function or Macro will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub RangetoColumn()
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Count As Long

    Set CurrentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")'-->change Sheet1 to your source sheet
    Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")'-->change Sheet2 to your target sheet
    LastRow = CurrentSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Count = 1
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        LastColumn = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For j = 1 To LastColumn
            TargetSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, j).Value
            Count = Count + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Code will read Range from `Sheet1` and will create a Column in `Sheet2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fulfills the requirements.

Comment: @TanvirSourov - Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this tutorial should help you : [tutorial](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1172-excel-transpose-multiple-columns-into-one-column.html)
you can try that solution for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&` in both cells. Try like this `A1&B1` to combine the data in cell `A1` and cell `B1`; copy and paste, then enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

this will have all current sheet cells listed down its column A and cleared all other adjacent columns

```
Option Explicit

Sub RangeToOneColumn()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myArr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<== change it to your needs
        lastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim myArr(0 To lastRow - 1)
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            myArr(i - 1) = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng))
        Next i
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents

        j = 1
        For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
            .Cells(j, 1).Resize(UBound(myArr(i))) = Application.Transpose(myArr(i))
            j = j + UBound(myArr(i))
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

since it uses array, it runs faster than iterating a coping&pasting through cells