# Range in multiple rows to single column vba

Tags: excel, row, col, vba

I have used [Mrig's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818001/multiple-rows-and-columns-to-single-column-excel) in to insert a range in multiple rows into a single column in a second worksheet, but cannot ask a supplementary question there :-(

Is there some way to add a blank row between each inserted range?

Thanks!

My version of Mrig's code is:

```
Sub RangetoColumn()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Count As Long

Set CurrentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
LastRow = CurrentSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Count = 1
For i = 1 + 1 To LastRow 
    LastColumn = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 5 To j + 1
        TargetSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, j).Value
        Count = Count + 1
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: After the next j add another counter. Count = count + 1

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but

```
    TargetSheet.Range("A" & (Count*2)).Value = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, j).Value
```

ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

```
Count = count + 1
```

after Next j inserts a row after the inserted range of rows, whereas `Range("A" & (Count*2))` inserts a row after every row, so `Count = count + 1` does what I need.